# What are all the losing endings I need to get for the "101 ways to die" achievement?

Tags: achievements, the-last-express

*The Last Express: Gold Edition* on Steam has an achievement named "101 ways to die", which is to experience all the losing endings. What are all of these losing endings are there? I seem to be missing one or two of them, so I'd like a list to compare. I found [this one](http://steamcommunity.com/app/252710/discussions/0/648812916887414603/), but it seems to be incomplete.

By the way, I have noticed that it doesn't seem like there are actually 101 losing endings, since I recall I was able to get 25% progress on the achievement with just the first four endings. Although perhaps the game counts multiple ways to get a certain ending all at once (like multiple ways to die in a fight).

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there some way I can improve the question?

Comment: Seems good to me. +1

Comment: The question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer [I found this guide](http://steamcommunity.com/app/252710/discussions/0/648812916887414603/), but it was incomplete. I seem to have missed the guide that you found. It was my understanding that trying to achieve it myself and attempting to find a guide was enough research effort.

Comment: You didn't show any effort at all, and I'm doubting that you actually put any since you stopped looking after the very first result on Google.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I'm sorry that you thought I didn't put any research effort into this. I found the guide I linked to by searching the guides section in the Steam app, but the one you linked to did not show up. I just checked my search engine and the one you pointed to is my sixth result (I believe I checked the first four), however this question is now my second result. So now we have a more direct and easy to find resource for everyone, which seems like a win (and fits with [meta consensus](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10235/47878) that questions like that aren't so bad).

Comment: And I'm sorry you're taking this so personally. Your question got downvoted, and I decided to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick Google search, I found [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=337945040) listing all the losing endings. Spoilers follow:

> Past Paris part of journey
>
> - You don't touch Tyler's body and the conductor finds it.
> - The conductor finds you with the body.
> - The conductor finds you with blood on your jacket.
> - You put Tyler's body in the bed but you don't close the bed.
> - You knock a lot of times on the harem doors and you're kicked out of the train.
> - You talk to Schmidt before finding Tyler's body. He goes to his compartment and finds it.
> - You use the emergency brake (suicide button).
> - Milos comes to your compartment, and finds Tyler's body on the floor or on the bed.
> - Milos kills you with a knife (throat or stomach).
> - You hide Tyler's body in the bed, but you don't get rid of it before conductor comes to prepare your bed.
>
> Eperney
>
> - If you threw Tyler's body through the window during day time, police comes to the train. If you don't hide it's game over.
>
> Wels
>
> - You don't hide the Firebird with Max: Kahina finds it sooner or later and the game ends in Vienna.
> - Tatiana catches you with the Firebird in your hands: you can't get it again and Kahina gets it.
> - You jump to the locomotive from the roof twice.
> - Kahina kills you because she finds you in Kronos's room before the concert.
> - Kahina kills you because you didn't bring the Firebird or the gold.
> - You give the Firebird to Kronos.
> - You didn't show the gold to Schmidt, so the serbian didn't get their weapons and kill you.
> - Vesna kills you with a knife.
> - You didn't save Anna from Vesna, and you find her body.
> - The conductor finds Anna's body with the luggage.
>
> Galanta
>
> - You don't steal the clock from Alexei's luggage.
>
> Before Budapest
>
> - You don't find the bomb.
> - You talk to Abbot before defusing the bomb.
> - You mess up defusing the bomb: don't get the box, open the box, use your hands to defuse...
>
> Belgrad
>
> - Serbian #1 knocks you out.
> - You go to the restaurant and Vesna kills you.
> - Serbian #2 crowbar kills you with a crowbar.
> - Vesna kills you with her sword.
> - You're still standing up on the roof when the train approaches the tunnel.
> - You didn't unhook the passenger cars when you get to the locomotive.
> - You let the train stop.
> - You didn't stop the train but you didn't unhook the passenger cars.
>
> Before Constantinople
>
> - You left the firebird in the unhooked cars.
> - You wait a lot of time to get the Firebird to Kronos.
> - You don't give the firebird to Kronos.
> - You don't open the Firebird.
> - You don't use the whistle.

Comment: So there are not actually 101?

Comment: Not that I can tell